# Unwind segue to embedded view controller (container view's VC)?

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode, storyboard, segue

I have a Parent VC in a navigation controller.  The Parent has a Child VC embedded in a container view (using embed segue). The child VC itself does a push segue to an Input VC -- this pushes away the Parent.

[image]

The problem is that when my Input VC is done and wants to unwind back to the Child VC (that's the one that pushed it, so it should take care of the answer) nothing happens. In contrast, when I unwind to the Parent (as a test to make sure I did everything right) everything works.

In other words, what I want to do is to take care of the connected IBAction method in the Child VC.

Is there no way to unwind to an IBAction that's implemented in an embedded VC?

Comment: I'm not exactly sure what you're trying to do, but if you pushed to InputVC, you should pop to go back, not use an unwind segue. If you need to send data back to the child, then you should use a delegate protocol to do that.

Comment: Okay, is there a reason for this? I mean, unwind segues do work with navigation controllers in general and their purpose is in part to avoid having to define lots of trivial delegate protocols. Btw, like I said I do a push segue, not a push from code.

Comment: No, I suppose there's no reason why you can't use unwind segues for this purpose, as long as you're hiding the back button or replacing it with your own button that will call the unwind segue. As to why you can unwind to the child controller, who knows? I tried it, and got the same results as you. I don't know if this is a bug, or just a consequence of pushing from a controller that's not directly embedded in a navigation controller.

Comment: Maybe I should rethink for now and handle everything in the parent VC... But doing segues from the child VCs and taking care of the unwinding in the same place seems like good cohesion.